# Twig, is it possible to override an tag atribute of parent template from a child template?

Tags: twig

I have two templates, a parent template and a child template. 
I want know if its possible to add 'properly' a class to a tag in the parent template from the child template ? and if yes, how ?

By example, if I have this parent.html.twig file :

```
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

And this child.html.twig file :

```
{% extends 'parent.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    {# ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

From the child.html.twig file, can I add a class to the body tag ? and how ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the parent template adding a block, as example:

<kbd>parent.html.twig</kbd>

```
<body {% block bodyclass %}{% endblock %}>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

and use in the child:

<kbd>child.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends 'parent.html.twig' %}
{% block bodyclass %}class="child-class"{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    {# ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

You can try in this [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/9yfpn5)